# Angular busy cursor not shown while waiting for Promise

Tags: angular, promise, spinner

I am trying to display a busy cursor in my angular app, 
the busy cursor is to be shown we are process some data and not actually a service call.
So I surrounded the logic that has to be performed in a method which atually return a promise.
I am displaying this promise as Busy in my html.
The busy symbol is not shown during the process.

```
TS.FILE
 busy: Promise<any>;
 @ViewChild('component') ComponentView;
              this.busy = this.asyncPromiseViewtest().then(data => {
                 //do some stuff
              });

                asyncPromiseViewtest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(this.component.processFunc());
    });
  }
HTML:
  <div [ngBusy]="{busy: [busy], backdrop: true, delay: 200, minDuration: 600}">
```

Comment: That promise appears to resolve immediately, so you want get a chance to see the busy symbol

Comment: `asyncPromiseViewtest` makes no sense. `processFunc` needs to return a promise (and resolve it at the right time), and you should be able to call it directly.

Comment: @Bergi, I have another function something similar which doesnot return promise but show me a spinner. Here is the snipper of code. The function that is being processed is in the same .ts file though.  this.busy = this.asyncPromise().then(data => {
                 //do some stuff
              });

                asyncPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(this.processData());
    });

processData() 
{
//no promise return
//do some logic
}

Comment: Please post the code of `processFunc` and `processData`, that seems to be what you need help with